# Is there a way to fix files not showing as available? (WITHOUT PROJECT FILE)

Tags: labview

Good day,
At work we were using a valve testing program for well over 20 years and all worked perfectly until we reached measurement #10000.
By the looks of it if the serial number is higher than 9999, it doesn't show up anymore in the files list:

[image: Trevitest Printing Program front panel]

[image: File Explorer showing 'trevites' data folder content]

The problem is that we don't have the original project file.
So we tried to delete any reference to the latest serial number we could (cfg,ini files) deleting all the previous measurements, even copying the whole folder from another laptop that hasn't reached 10k but nothing worked.

Right now the only solution that works is renaming the newest file and i also can change the initials from for example "EA" to "AB"

So is there a way to reset the increments? or is it possible to change what files it looks for without the project file?

Edit: LabVIEW version is probably 7.0

Comment: This is unlikely to be a LabVIEW issue and is nearly certain to be a problem with the program written in LabVIEW. Having worked on the execution system, I can say with fair certainty there's no arbitrary limitation on files that fits your description.

Comment: Yep, that is problem of that particular executable. Maybe, it validates name by length, or something like that.

Comment: Yea unfortunately that seems to be the case, which is a shame since we only have the executable. The file where it keeps track of the serial number is still nowhere to be found too.